# The probability of the union of two events

Tags: probability

Does the union of two events exclude that those events may occur together?  In other words, is it the same as an exclusive or?

$p(E_1 \cup E_2) = p(E_1) + p(E_2) - p(E_1 \cap E_2)$

The reason I ask is because the above equation explicitly subtracts the probability of the events occurring together.

Comment: No. The intersection event $E_1\cap E_2$ occurs in both $E_1$ and $E_2$, so if you don't subtract one out it will be counted twice. Another way to look at it is to look at the following equality: $p(E_1 \cup E_2) = p(E_1\setminus E_2) + P( E_1\cap E_2) + p(E_2\setminus E_1)$.

Comment: Informally, you can think of $\Pr(A)$ as the "weight" of $A$. So if you add the weights of $E_1$ and of $E_2$, and $E_1\cap E_2)$ has non-zero weight, you get more than the weight of $E_1\cup E_2)$. How much more? By the weight of $E_1\cap E_2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know that if $A$, $B$ and $C$ are mutually disjoint events i.e. if $A \cap B = B \cap C = C \cap A = \emptyset$, then $$\mathbb{P}(A \cup B \cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C)$$

Now consider two events $E_1$ and $E_2$ that are not mutually disjoint events i.e. if $E_1 \cap E_2 \neq \emptyset$ and we want to evaluate $P(E_1 \cup E_2)$.

From the figure, it is apparent that the intersection $E_1 \cap E_2$ is counted twice: once as part of $E_1$ and once as part of $E_2$. Hence, it needs to be subtracted off. For a more rigorous derivation, see below the figure.

[image]

The idea is to split $E_1 \cup E_2$ into three disjoint sets as follows. $$E_1 \cup E_2 = (E_1 \backslash E_2) \cup (E_1 \cap E_2) \cup (E_2 \backslash E_1)$$

Note that $(E_1 \backslash E_2)$, $(E_1 \cap E_2)$ and $(E_2 \backslash E_1)$ are mutually disjoint sets. Hence, we have that
$$P(E_1 \cup E_2) = P((E_1 \backslash E_2) \cup (E_1 \cap E_2) \cup (E_2 \backslash E_1))\\ = P(E_1 \backslash E_2) + P(E_1 \cap E_2) + P(E_2 \backslash E_1)$$
Call the above equation $\star$.

Now note that $$(E_1 \backslash E_2) \cup (E_1 \cap E_2) = E_1$$
Since $(E_1 \backslash E_2)$, $(E_1 \cap E_2)$ are mutually disjoint sets, we have that $$P(E_1 \backslash E_2) + P(E_1 \cap E_2) = P(E_1)$$
Hence, $$P(E_1 \backslash E_2) = P(E_1) - P(E_1 \cap E_2)$$
Similarly, since $$(E_1 \cap E_2) \cup (E_2 \backslash E_1) = E_2$$ are mutually disjoint sets, we have that $$ P(E_1 \cap E_2) + P(E_2 \backslash E_1) = P(E_2)$$
Hence,
$$ P(E_2 \backslash E_1) = P(E_2) - P(E_1 \cap E_2)$$ Now plug in for $P(E_1 \backslash E_2)$ and $P(E_2 \backslash E_1)$ in $\star$, to get what you want.

Comment: What does the notation with \ mean?

Comment: @user1038665 The notation $A \backslash B$ means the set of elements in the set $A$ but not in the set $B$. Also, as Austin Mohr has pointed out, note that the intersection $E_1 \cap E_2$ is counted twice: once as part of $E_1$ and once as part of $E_2$. Hence, it needs to be subtracted off.

Comment: @marvis which program was used for the graphics?

Comment: @MaoYiyi I drew it using TikZ in LaTeX and cut copy pasted it.

Answer (score 2):

The formula you give is the correct way to determine $\Pr(E_1 \cup E_2)$ (often referred to as the inclusion-exclusion principle). The union of the two events, however, does include outcomes occurring in both events. Formally,
$$
E_1 \cup E_2 = \{\omega \mid \omega \in E_1 \text{ (inclusive) or } \omega \in E_2 \}.
$$
The reason we subtract $\Pr(E_1 \cap E_2)$ in the formula you give is because outcomes occurring in the intersection would otherwise be counted *twice*. To see this, it is easier to just think of sets. Is it true that
$$
|A \cup B| = |A| + |B|?
$$
No. For a simple counterexample to this claim, let $A = B = \{1\}$. We know $A \cup B = \{1\}$, so $|A \cup B| = 1$, while $|A| + |B| = 2$. The reason is because the lefthand side counts the element $1$ a single time, while it is counted *twice* on the righthand side (once because it belongs to $A$ and once because it belongs to $B$). An analogous argument applies to probabilities.

Comment: Why would the intersection be counted twice?